# Android Room database. Creating and dropping tables with table name as parameter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room

**Is there any way I can create and drop tables similar to a 'RawQuery'?**

I tried with a **`@RawQuery`** annotation *(which it would be the perfect solution for me)* but when I am compiling I get an error saying methods annotated with `RawQuery` can't return **void**.

I read only **SELECT, UPDATE** and **DELETE** statements are allowed when using **`@Query`**.

I would like to achieve the "creation or deletion of tables" by passing a `tablename` as a parameter, something like the following:

```
@Query("DROP TABLE :name")
void deleteTable (String name);
```

**Any ideas on how to achieve this?**

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html

Answer (score 3):

[Official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RawQuery) states that,

> **`RawQuery`** serves as an escape hatch where you can build your own SQL query at runtime but still use **Room** to convert it into
>   objects.
>
> **`RawQuery`** methods must return a *non-void* type. *If you want to execute a raw query that does not return any value, use
>   [**RoomDatabase#query**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase#query(android.arch.persistence.db.SupportSQLiteQuery)) methods.*

*or use it like,*

```
@RawQuery
int deleteTable (SupportSQLiteQuery query); //We can return int status like it used to return with database.delete()

//Usage

dao.deleteTable(
        new SimpleSQLiteQuery("DROP TABLE tablename")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The ting is, wit Room, you don't have to "drop" tables, the tables re created based on your entity classes (annotated with `@Entity`).

As far as I know, you usually need to drop tables in case the columns change or there are some updates on the "structure", with Room there's no point in doing this unless you change the structure of your entity that can't be automatically handled by the migration. In this case, Room gives you the chance to do the migration by yourself. Check the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions
But like the documentation states, be really careful with this.